# Why does my code stop after the first test case? (Problem -- https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/codemonk/)

Tags: python-3.x

Please review my code for the problem given in the title, it stops after showing correct output for the first test case and shows Runtime error if I put t > 1 in Hackerearth IDE.

```
t = int(input())
while t > 0:
    t = t - 1
    n, k = map(int, input().split())
    A = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    p = []
    if k > n:
        k = k - n
    elif k == n:
        k = 0
    else:
        k = k
    for j in range(k):
        x = A.pop()
        p.append(x)
    p = p[::-1]
    for j in range(len(A)):
        p.append(A[j])
    print(*p)
```

Comment: Please show the complete error message with traceback that you get. It contains useful information to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this site can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") and ["How do I ask and answer homework questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions "How do I ask and answer homework questions?") pages for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: It only shoes NZEC runtime error on HackerEarth IDE nothing else, whereas on my personal Vim and codechef IDE the code stops after printing output of the first test case without showing any errors